# Uploading a large file from phone

Tags: http, rest, upload, asp.net-web-api, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to write a WP8 app that needs to upload a large amount of data back to my server. My server runs on ASP.net and implements REST using WebAPI.

I've gotten to a point where I can upload small amount of data, say 2-5MB using a POST and transfer them over to Azure blobs. Now, I'm thinking about moving a decent amount of data, say ~40-50MB from the phone using the background transfer API defined here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955(v=vs.105).aspx

The phone API supports -

Over cellular connection - 5 MB,

Over Wi-Fi connection with battery power - 20 MB

Over Wi-Fi connection with external power - 100 MB

The part that I'm struggling to understand is -

1. The MSDN kb article recommends that the server implement range requests, which is fair. However, it doesn't say how much could be chunked at a time. Can my upload server config be unbounded for request size?

I would prefer to keep the client as 'dumb' as possible and use the existing transfer APIs on the phone. My concerns are around performance of my server and how much memory would be available on the server if I start seeing considerable traffic on the server. Can someone give me pointers for server best practices to accept large amounts of data?

Comment: I 'think' range requests are only for download or server response scenarios. for example, if you are downloading huge file and the connection is lost, then you could request the server for the file from where it left off. I was told that there is no spec from Http related to request side of range requests, even though a custom implementation seems to be not difficult to imagine. Regarding general uploading of large files like 100 MB, you can change the default buffer policy in Web API to read the incoming request in Streamed mode rather than buffered mode.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundTranferRequest does not support the Range header. [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransferrequest.headers%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Implement your own upload and download client and you can use Range and also bypass the various size limitations.